# Can the 1m Apple USB C cable charge the 13 inch MacBook Pro at full speed?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, charging, power

I'm wondering if the [1m Apple USB C cable](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MUF72AM/A/usb-c-charge-cable-1-m) can charge the 13 inch MacBook Pro safely at full speed (i.e. 60W). From my knowledge, all certified USB C cables support 60W charging, which means it *should*. However, it's really hard to tell if that's actually the case from the website, because the only thing it says on that site is that it's "recommended for use with the iPad Pro and the 18W power adapter."

I know that the 2m Apple USB C cable is able to provide up to 100W of power; however, I am interested specifically in the 1m cable which comes by default with iPads.

I have been looking at Apple support articles and none of them mention anything about this cable—they only talk about the 2m cable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> *In practice, my experience is yes. Every single iPad cable has not been an issue for charging any iPad and 13 Inch MacBook Pro and MacBook One.*

Comment: I so wanted to post yes it works, but character limits...

Comment: It is actually useful to know that this is based on experience and not an argument based on compliance to some standard.

Answer (score 4):

@bmike's answer is correct, but there are some details to be aware of with USB-C cables:

1. In some cases, USB-C cables **not** made by Apple will not work properly (or even at all) with Apple hardware & chargers.
2. In some cases, Apple-manufactured USB-C cables will not work with other devices.

Why? Apple must have cables that are [`e-Marked`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C), and other devices may [require non-e-Marked cables](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105819/83790). Standards are wonderful, no?

Comment: That's interesting—I wish USB C standards were a bit more standard

Comment: I wish, too. But USB 3.0 and later standards are more complex than an average cable ot hub producer would like (the proper word would be an utter mess and not a standard). Every single USB 3.0 or later cable (no matter if it is USB-A to B, A to C or C to C) has a CPU and a firmware (and bugs) inside. To add insult to injury, the Power Delivery part of the standard came rather late and a lot of wannabe standards for more than those 10-ish watts of the otherwise rock-solid USB2 emerged in the meantime (QuickCharge and friends). One can only hope these things will settle in a while.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi foundation has admitted that they've screwed up in that case, and have designed a new board revision to work with e-Marked cables.

Comment: @lights0123: Yes - they have. And if they had a program to replace the "mistakes" that were bought, that would be even better.

Comment: Holy carp. I can't wait for USB4.